# HTML input required attribute not working for a field

Tags: html

I am trying to do some client side validations and when I am adding the required attribute to my HTML inputs but it works only for some fields.

```
<input type = "text" name="description" id = "descriptionOfChange" required> //this works
<input type = "text" name = "cid" id = "cid" required> //this does not work(also is my primary key. Not sure if that is the reason why)
<input type="text" name = "dateOfCompletion" id="datepicker" required /> //this works too
```

Comment: Close your `input` tags..

Comment: Are you sure? This is working fine for me.. Check the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e8CMT/

Comment: @tymeJV Not needed unless it's XHTML (very unlikely).

Comment: I suppose it's more of a preference thing to me...as you have one `input` closed at the end and the other 2 open, be consistent.

Comment: It worked fine for me. You can check the fiddle. Although it will not prompt any error if there is any white space in the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine as it is, but just to make sure, try this:

```
<input type = "text" name = "description" id = "descriptionOfChange" required /> 
<input type = "text" name = "cid" id = "cid_css" required /> 
<input type = "text" name = "dateOfCompletion" id = "datepicker" required />
```

Although, semiclosing this tag is not necessary, it can make some browsers behave in a weird way, especially IE.

Comment: Yup that worked. I believe it was just consistently closing input tags. Will keep that in mind next time. Thanks:)